# Cannot connect using ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA

Tags: tls, certificates, linux, openssl

I try to establish an SSL connection using the `ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA` cipher using OpenSSL, but it fails saying `"no shared cipher"`:

On the server, I run:

```
$ openssl s_server -cert selfsigned_cert.pem -key selfsigned_key.pem
ACCEPT
ERROR
140662855206568:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1236:
```

On the client:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myserver:4433 -cipher ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
CONNECTED(00000003)
140237192541856:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
```

Is it because of the server's certificate?
It is a self signed certificate :

```
$ openssl x509 -in selfsigned_cert.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number:
            a9:30:4a:0b:b0:2a:7a:ab
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=FR, ST=Some-State, L=Paris, O=Foo, OU=Bar, CN=selfsigned/emailAddress=moi
        Validity
            Not Before: Sep 14 12:29:49 2015 GMT
            Not After : Aug 29 12:29:49 2017 GMT
        Subject: C=FR, ST=Some-State, L=Paris, O=Foo, OU=Bar, CN=selfsigned/emailAddress=moi
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:df:2f:1f:ff:ce:21:9c:e4:e3:9c:c8:ba:a2:d1:
                    f3:6a:73:a4:af:d6:da:5a:f9:b8:dc:49:ce:5d:89:
                    03:88:6d:11:06:7e:9a:1c:93:1b:95:25:c8:e6:c3:
                    b5:5f:ed:96:2d:29:bf:77:a6:a9:25:33:8b:9a:69:
                    fd:88:52:94:03:a5:6b:ce:5a:a4:ad:ca:39:51:00:
                    09:14:4f:37:ce:84:8c:3e:d6:43:df:55:11:52:95:
                    0b:64:4d:72:e3:43:52:98:cc:51:87:70:0a:c0:78:
                    8a:b8:8f:4b:3c:37:9a:3a:a6:6f:87:81:a9:42:19:
                    02:f2:9f:36:2d:30:d0:40:01
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        50:28:61:05:4e:a0:58:e1:5a:e4:0a:cf:e9:9c:bb:48:f0:f2:
        ed:e9:51:41:be:2c:b2:66:0d:21:bb:94:c4:49:c4:38:15:e5:
        b7:b3:d9:ce:4e:af:b3:bd:47:3d:1f:54:21:a6:1d:8a:15:5c:
        ef:bb:28:d0:3b:e9:9b:cb:2d:30:b9:fb:47:ef:25:15:4a:38:
        e3:81:9c:70:d9:22:55:71:d5:d8:75:5e:23:5d:88:67:31:d3:
        84:2c:2e:ad:ec:3c:55:d1:95:f6:43:29:cd:c3:ac:9c:e2:5f:
        8f:c8:1e:24:4a:c8:57:d2:84:b5:d3:f8:35:40:5b:75:28:e4:
        a5:3d
```

Without the `"-cipher ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA"` argument, the client connects successfully to my server.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

### Use ECDH*E* instead.

I think you're mixing up ECDH and ECDHE.

```
$ openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL' | sort | grep ECDH | grep -- '-RSA-AES256-SHA '
      0xC0,0x0F - ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x14 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

- The `"ECDH-"` one uses fixed DH parameters inside the certificate. This is rarely used. And your certificate is not one such fixed-DH certificate. It has the line `"Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption"`, so it's the regular RSA type certificate.
- The `"ECDHE-"` one uses **ephemeral** DH parameters. This is the one that you can use with your certificate.

### Further reading

- Anonymous/fixed/ephemeral (EC)DH: OpenSSL Wiki: [Diffie-Hellman in SSL/TLS](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman#Diffie-Hellman_in_SSL.2FTLS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand using "ECDH-" ciphers is not recommended for a production site. I just want to run a quick test to ensure all supported ciphers work fine. And I'm wondering how to generate the server's certificate to establish a connection with such cipher.

Comment: Don't. Just remove fixed ECDH from the list of supported ciphers. But if you really, really insist, then have a look at these questions: CrSE: [Static DH/Static ECDH certificate using OpenSSL](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19452/static-dh-static-ecdh-certificate-using-openssl). SecSE: [OpenSSL generate different types of self signed certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/openssl-generate-different-types-of-self-signed-certificate).